# Selenium checkbox not being checked

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to test the privacy statement checkbox on this website

[image]

The HTML code of the checkbox is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="registryTandCs" id="registryTandCs" value="" class="form-check-input form-check-input--custom" required="required" data-parsley-multiple="registryTandCs">
```

The code that I am using to check this is

```
driver.findElement(By.id("registryTandCs")).click();
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.
I have also tried

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.id("registryTandCs"));
checkBox.click();
```

If it's any help, the website in question is [here](https://www.dunnesstores.com/customer/login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that when you are trying to click the checkbox other element is getting clicked. You can see an input and label tags are getting overlapped ***(Please check the attached image).***

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Always check the error stacktrace.**

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element 
<input type="checkbox" name="registryTandCs" id="registryTandCs" value="" class="form-check-input form-check-input--custom" required="required" data-parsley-multiple="registryTandCs"> 
is not clickable at point (655, 517). 
Other element would receive the click: 
<label for="registryTandCs" class="form-check-label form-check-label--grey">...</label>
```

**Working solution:** *There is two way to solve this problem.*

**Using Action Class:**

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.id("registryTandCs"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(checkBox).click().build().perform();
```

**Using JavascriptExecutor:**

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.id("registryTandCs"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *id*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("registryTandCs")).click();
  ```
- *name*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.name("registryTandCs")).click();
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#registryTandCs[name='registryTandCs']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='registryTandCs' and @name='registryTandCs']")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *id*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("registryTandCs"))).click();
  ```
- *name*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("registryTandCs"))).click();
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#registryTandCs[name='registryTandCs']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='registryTandCs' and @name='registryTandCs']"))).click();
  ```